# Ace editor: How to get position of keyboard event

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Currently, I am getting events whenever any key is pressed in my ace editor, via this javascript code:

```
editor.keyBinding.addKeyboardHandler({
    handleKeyboard: function(data, hash, keyString, keyCode, event) {
```

`keyString` contains the actual key pressed, but how do I find the position (i.e. row and column) of where the key event took place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
 var currentPosition = editor.selection.getCursor();
```

You could use the **currentPosition** to find the row and column position where the key event took place. (currentPosition.row and currentPosition.column)

Answer (score 1):

Key event doesn't take place in any position, but in the editor as a whole.

You can use `editor.getCursorPosition()` to find the position of the cursor.